# Delay Functional Equation: $f(t) - f(t-\tau) = u(t)$

Tags: functional-equations

Up front, I do not have any background in functional equations.  Maybe this is an easy problem, maybe it is an impossible problem; I do not know.

I am trying to solve the following equation for $f(t)$:
\begin{equation}
   f(t) - f(t-\tau) = u(t),
\end{equation}
where $\tau$ is some constant and $u$ is an arbitrary smooth function of $t$.  I read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3608687/functional-equation-with-delay-ft-pm-ft-tau-g) which suggests that there is a homogeneous and a particular component to a solution.  I am only interested in the particular part.  Are there any relevant approaches to find particular solutions of functional equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.

Using the Laplace transform we have

$$
F(s)-e^{-s\tau}F(s)-e^{-s\tau}\int_{-\tau}^0e^{-s\eta}f(\eta)d\eta = U[s)
$$

Assuming that $f(\eta) = 0$ for $-\tau\le \eta \le 0$ we have

$$
F(s) = U(s)(1-e^{-s\tau})^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I think methods for finding solutions depend on the quality of $u$. For example set
$$
f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty u(t-k\tau)
$$
in case that this series is convergent for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then
$$
f(t)-f(t-\tau) 
$$
$$
=(u(t)+u(t-\tau)+ u(t-2\tau) + \dots) - (u(t-\tau)+u(t-2\tau)+ u(t-3\tau) + \dots) = u(t).
$$
This works for example if $u$ has compact support or for $u(t)=\exp(-t^2)$.

Comment: I like both of the solutions, but I think Cesareo's solution will be more useful for my particular problem.  Thank you for the insight!